# Operator "()" in template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a template class where typename is a pointer to a function:

`CHook<NTSTATUS(__stdcall*)(PHANDLE,ACCESS_MASK,POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,HANDLE,PCLIENT_ID,PCONTEXT,PUSER_STACK,BOOLEAN)> hZwCreateThread;`

Now I call them like hZwCreateThread.Call()(...params...); but I want to make it hZwCreateThread(...params...) using () operator overloading.
This code:

```
const FuncType operator()() { return m_OrigFunc; };
```

Makes it work only in such way: hZwCreateThread()(...params...). How to make it work as I wrote above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conversion operator.

```
template <typename F>
struct CHook {
    F m_OrigFunc;
    CHook (F func) : m_OrigFunc(func) {}
    operator F () const { return m_OrigFunc; }
};
```

This would allow code like this:

```
CHook<int(*)(const char *,...)> chook(printf);
chook("%s\n", "Hello world!");
```